# Endings of 2 adjectives after mit

Tags: adjective, dative

I read this sentence in Harry Potter:
"Okay, sagte Harry mit ungewohnt trockenem Mund".

I thought it should be "mit ungewohntem trockenen Mund".

What's the rule for adjective endings when there are multiple adjectives?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question asked, but in the example "ungewohnt" is an adverb, "unusually", modifying "trocken". I'm sure JK Rowling wasn't saying Harry's mouth was unusual, which is what your question would imply.

Comment: @RDBury Isn't "ungewohnt" an adjective that further describes the dry mouth? Why is it an adverb?

Comment: @RDBury I think I see what you're saying. It's "with an unusually dry mouth", not "with an unusual, dry, mouth".

Comment: The thing is, adverbs aren't marked by a suffix in German the way they are in English; if anything you can only tell by the lack of suffix, though adjectives can lack a suffix too depending on how it's used: "Sein Mund war trocken." In some cases you just have to use context or word order to tell adverb from adjective.

Comment: @RHa - I'm not sure that answers the actual question, though it does explain the example. I think searching on "Parallelflexion" will yield the answer, but I'm not a native speaker and the language seems to allow more than option.

Comment: @RHa that does answer the question, thankyou.